# Adding crosswalk to my cordova-polymer project

Tags: android, ios, cordova, polymer, crosswalk-runtime

I Am Following this tutorial:
http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/

and i have found out that the polymer part in the app fails to work probebly beacause my device android version is only 4.2.1 .

i've heard that crosswalk project can open the chromium webview instead of the default android webview so my question is:
1) how do i implement it to the project above.
2) how well polymer works on ios / how do i do the same thing that crosswalk does on ios since there is no chrome in ios.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Crosswalk-based Cordova:

https://www.crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/develop_an_application

there is not much effort to migrate from apache Cordova to Crosswalk-based Cordova

And here is the download:
https://www.crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/downloads

Comment: once crosswalk is integrated will super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); do the trick or do we have to use some other method to use crosswalk's webview

Answer (score 0):

download Intel XDK (its free) http://xdk-software.intel.com/
copy your app to new project, click on build tab, choose crosswalk.
you can also click on Preview on device it will open the app in your connected device

you can read more here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/blogs/what-is-crosswalk

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing with the ionic framework? if not, how can i add polymer to the project?

Comment: sorry I dont understand you, if you asking about intel xdk so yes you can use any html/js you want  @user2221776

Comment: i have downloaded the intel xdk. gotta say it pretty freaking awesome. but how do i add polymer to it?